Android Studio Spinner issue
I created a spinner where I want the app to output the value the spinner stops at, however, if the spinner pointer stopped at let's say Italy, The text output is you choose India, I've tried everything I know but nothing is working for some reason, not sure what I'am missing there!
Below is my CustomWheelView appreciate your kind input in advance :)
package com.tummyspinner.app

import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Color
import android.graphics.LinearGradient
import android.graphics.Paint
import android.graphics.RectF
import android.graphics.Shader
import android.graphics.Typeface
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.View
import kotlin.math.min

class CustomWheelView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private val paint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)
    private val textPaint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG).apply {
        color = Color.WHITE
        textSize = 40f
        textAlign = Paint.Align.CENTER
        typeface = Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD)
    }
    private val gradientColors = listOf(
        Color.parseColor("#F44336"), // Red
        Color.parseColor("#FF9800"), // Orange
        Color.parseColor("#FFEB3B"), // Yellow
        Color.parseColor("#4CAF50"), // Green
        Color.parseColor("#2196F3"), // Blue
        Color.parseColor("#9C27B0"), // Purple
        Color.parseColor("#E91E63")  // Pink
    )
    private var rectF = RectF()
    private var angle = 0f
    private var isSpinning = false

    private val segments = listOf("Italian", "Indian", "Chinese", "Mexican", "American", "Thai", "Japanese")

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)

        val width = width.toFloat()
        val height = height.toFloat()
        val radius = min(width, height) / 2
        rectF.set(width / 2 - radius, height / 2 - radius, width / 2 + radius, height / 2 + radius)

        val sweepAngle = 360f / segments.size

        for (i in segments.indices) {
            paint.shader = LinearGradient(
                rectF.centerX(), rectF.top,
                rectF.centerX(), rectF.bottom,
                gradientColors[i % gradientColors.size],
                gradientColors[(i + 1) % gradientColors.size],
                Shader.TileMode.CLAMP
            )
            canvas.drawArc(rectF, angle + i * sweepAngle, sweepAngle, true, paint)

            val textAngle = Math.toRadians((angle + i * sweepAngle + sweepAngle / 2).toDouble())
            val x = (width / 2 + radius * 0.65 * Math.cos(textAngle)).toFloat()
            val y = (height / 2 + radius * 0.65 * Math.sin(textAngle)).toFloat()
            canvas.drawText(segments[i], x, y, textPaint)
        }
    }

    private var isListenerFired = false // Prevent multiple messages

    fun spinWheel() {
        if (!isSpinning) {
            isSpinning = true
            isListenerFired = false // Reset the flag at the start of the spin
            val randomAngle = (360 * 5 + (0..360).random()).toFloat() // Random spin angle

            animate()
                .rotation(randomAngle)
                .setDuration(3000)
                .withEndAction {
                    // Bounce effect
                    animate().rotationBy(5f).setDuration(100).withEndAction {
                        animate().rotationBy(-5f).setDuration(100).withEndAction {
                            // Final calculations
                            angle = (angle + randomAngle) % 360 // Update current angle
                            isSpinning = false
                            invalidate()

                            val sweepAngle = 360f / segments.size
                            val correctedAngle = (360 - (angle % 360) + sweepAngle / 2) % 360
                            val selectedIndex = ((correctedAngle / sweepAngle).toInt() % segments.size)

                            // Ensure listener is invoked once
                            onWheelStoppedListener?.invoke(segments[selectedIndex])
                        }.start()
                    }.start()
                }
                .start()
        }
    }



    private var onWheelStoppedListener: ((String) -> Unit)? = null

    fun setOnWheelStoppedListener(listener: (String) -> Unit) {
        onWheelStoppedListener = listener
    }
}


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If the wheel has 6 values for example country names & let's say the wheel pointer stopped at Italy, the text output message says you selected India which is another value. Hope that clarifies

You'll need to specify where the pointer (visually) is located on the wheel.  Bear in mind the drawArc coordinate system has 0 degrees at the right as shown here.

My pointer is visually located at 270

figured it out! I changed the angle to 270 and it worked!!
val pointerAngle = (270 - rotation) % 360
That was helpful thank you so much :)
